# In a line chart, how do I change the last series in the Active Chart to secondary axis?

Tags: excel, vba

Current code assumes 4 series

```
Sub Macro1() 

    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).ChartType = xlArea
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).AxisGroup = 2

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you asking how to determine the `4` programmatically? `FullSeriesCollection` has a [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.fullseriescollection.count) property.

Comment: As @BigBen said, replace `4` with `ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count`

Answer (score 1):

As BigBen suggested, you can use the Count property to refer to the last series.  Accordingly, your macro can be re-written as follows...

```
Sub Macro1()

    With ActiveChart
        With .FullSeriesCollection(.FullSeriesCollection.Count)
            .ChartType = xlArea
            .AxisGroup = 2
        End With
    End With


End Sub
```